# How to do non commutative scalar to vector operations on a Spark Data Frame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

With a spark data frame, say I have a column of type double or int and I want to apply a scalar operation to it. If the operation is commutative (like addition) it's fine and I can do the following:

```
df.withColumn("RESULT", df("col") + 10)
```

But what if the operation is not commutative (like division)?

This would work

```
df.withColumn("RESULT", df("col") / 10)
```

but this does not work (error is Type mismatch)

```
df.withColumn("RESULT", 10 / df("col"))
```

Providing the raw sql would work, but then you have to deal with the maintenance of selecting the previous columns:

```
df.select("10 / col")
```

You could also inject the scalar value into the df, but then you would have to drop it.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. Just use SQL literal:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit

df.withColumn("RESULT", lit(10) / df("col"))
```

You can also use `selectExpr`:

```
df.selectExpr("*", "10 / col as result")
```

or `expr`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr

df.withColumn("RESULT", expr("10 / col"))
```

Comment: The problem with selectExpr("*"... is that I want to replace the column, not duplicate it. lit is what I am looking for.